# LFS binutils ../../gold/gold.h:29:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, linux-from-scratch

I'm working on LFS(11.0) for the first time

When installing the package binutils (https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/binutils.html)

(lfs chroot) root:/sources/binutils-2.37# make tooldir=/usr install -j1 # I encounter the fatal err and install fails :
../../gold/gold.h:29:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/bzip2-1.0.8# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 11.2.0

- tried removing nostdinc  and nostdinc++ on Makefile.in and configure.ac

There is no stddef.h on binutils directory, is this the issue ? Been struggling with this one.

Comment: It looks like you're in the source directory. You should have run `mkdir -v build` and `cd build`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I tried that too..same error 
it runs gcc with -I gold  (i.e, include the gold dir.), but unable to find stddef here. Still trying to resolve the error.

Comment: There isn't any reason to struggle, LFS will build without any issues if you follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with binutils 2.38. I tried binutils 2.39, still the same problem. I have `gcc` and `g++` in the chroot. I'm also building under `build/`.

Obviously this error goes away if you don't enable gold in `.configure`, but I would assume that's required for later packages.